# ¿Cómo cuento la cantidad de procesos que están corriendo?

Tags: linux, unix

Necesito mostrar la cantidad de procesos activos y lo hago con `ps | wc -l`.

El problema es que este comando me muestra un total de 4, pero debería mostrar 1 pues solamente tengo el proceso "bash".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay otra opción para este comando?, o alguna manera de restar los 3 procesos que me sobran?

---

por ejemplo si ejecuto el comando, me muestra una salida 4, y quiero que sea 1,
en pocas palabras restar 3 digitos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías agregar un ejemplo de tu salida actual y que es lo que esperas que devuelva por favor?

Comment: `wc -l` cuenta lineas

Comment: `ps h` muestra lista sin "header" ahí tenes una línea extra

Comment: el header, `ps` y `wc` son las (3) líneas extra que estas recibiendo

Comment: si eso lo se, lo que quería saber , es si habrá alguna forma de restar esas líneas

Comment: Curioso que sume uno al resultado final. Puedes quitar la cabecera con `ps --no-headers`.

Comment: Ps tambien es un porcesso ,wc tambien lo es y otro que diria que es al usar la pipline